# Operation that can succeed/fail -- return type & naming convention

Tags: c#, naming-conventions, return-value

What return type is appropriate for a method that can either complete successfully or fail due to its business logic?  And based on that return type, what would be the appropriate naming convention?

My instinct is that bool is most appropriate for a simple pass/fail. I've researched and found conventions for methods that infer a *trait* -- i.e. IsValid, HasFoo, ContainsBar, etc. But is that also the proper naming for an action like BuildHouse() or FlyKite() to clearly indicate whether the operation was successful?

I've tried it a few ways but each time I keep thinking that it looks weird and there must be a better practice....

```
bool IsHouseBuilt()
bool TryBuildHouse()
void BuildHouse(out bool success)
PassFailEnum BuildHouse() //seems a little excessive

bool IsKiteFlying()
bool TryFlyKite()
void FlyKite(out bool success)
PassFailEnum FlyKite()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All builtin methods in .NET that are trying to parse something to something else(e.g. `int.TryParse`) are called `TryParse` and return a `bool` and an `out` parameter.

So maybe:

```
public static bool TryBuildHouse(T input, out House house)
```

Comment: This is a good example for verifying the creation of an object. I'm wondering if the format would be significantly different for TryFlyKite, where we're just calling an action on an existing object?

Comment: Then in my opion `CanFlyKite` is more appropriate as property or method. If the action itself can fail (unexpectedly) an exception is the way to go. The `Try...` methods normally are trying to convert/create something from something different without throwing an exception.

Comment: At the risk of belaboring this, that brings up a good point. An action like FlyKite() can fail expectantly, say if windSpeed < 15mph at the time when FlyKite() is called. How would you return that? (I know the obvious answer is to set an IsFlying property on Kite, but let's pretend that we only care if the kite succeeded in liftoff. And also pretending that windSpeed can only be determined during the FlyKite() process.)

Comment: @RJB: Then the wind speed would be an argument for the method and you could throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` too fail as fast as poosible. However, there are multiple other possible ways for this specific action and the best answer depends on the concrete class and method.

Answer (score 1):

TryBuildHouse seems the most correct of your examples.

Answer (score 1):

The often accepted format for a method that tries to return a value is:

```
bool TryBuildHouse(out object thing);
```

The often accepted format for a method with no parameters that tries to succeed in doing something is whatever you want it to be, really... Some people prefer the `Try` prefix since it usually implies that it may not succeed, but I like to think that a `bool` return type also implies that it may not succeed. To each their own.

If the failure to build something is catastrophic (it absolutely SHOULD succeed all of the time), you should consider a void method that throws an appropriate exception in the rare instances of failure, and then catch or don't catch it based on your unique situational and environment requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest `TryParse` but you haven't stated whether the method actually returns an object as well. Conventionally, `TryParse` would suggest that there's an output. If you look at the `HashSet.Add` method, it returns a bool if successful but doesn't return an actual `out` value.

Therefore, from the sound of your case, I'd go for something like

```
/// <summary>
/// Builds a house
/// </summary>
/// <returns>true if house was built; false if house failed to build</returns>
public bool BuildHouse();
```

and document the fact that it returns a success/fail bool. If you plan to return an object, such as the house, then the `TryParse` option would make sense and your method would have an `out` parameter which will hold the newly created object.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider building a class that represents the information that would be desired for any type of call in your system, such as this:

```
public class ActionResult
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public List<string> Errors { get; }

    public ActionResult()
    {
        // Initialize whatever you want here
        Errors = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

Then when "bad" or "unexpected" things happen in your methods you can populate the `ActionResult` return type with error information that might be useful to the caller.

In your example you would use it like this:

```
ActionResult BuildHouse()
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots of possibilities. One I haven't seen mentioned is BuildHouse() returning a House object if it succeeds and returning null if it fails.